# Bentoml model supports rabbitmq message broker integration

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, rabbitmq, bentoml

Does Bentoml model supports rabbitmq message broker integration?
I had gone through many articles, I didn't find any documentation related to bentoml and rabbitmq integration.
Any reference article or code snippet  would be helpfull regarding rabbitmq integration with bentoml model.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.